# How to draw line graph by user input?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have idea about react but react native is new for me
my task is to make graph by taking x and y coordinates from user
i tried couple of libraries but all of them gives me some kind of errors
i am taking inputs from user in states when button clicked point should be added and when new values come and button pressed new point should added and line showd drawn from first point to second and so on.

**here is my code so far:**

```
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput,Button,Alert,Text } from "react-native";

const UselessTextInput = () => {
  const [x, setX] = React.useState("");
  const [y, setY] = React.useState("");

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(x) => setX(x)}
        placeholder="enter x"
        value={x}
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(y) => setY(y)}
        value={y}
        keyboardType="numeric"
        placeholder="enter y"
      />
      <Button
        title="Draw"
       onPress={() => // here call the function to draw graph}
      />
      <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>
        {x} {y}
        </Text>
        // here graph should displayed
      </SafeAreaView>
      
    
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
});

export default UselessTextInput
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my other Account i solved this problem and thought to answer so other can also get the benefit

well here is solution

first of all install library `npm i react-native-chart-kit`

then here are imports

```
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput,Button,Alert,Text, View, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import {
  LineChart,
} from "react-native-chart-kit";
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";
```

and here is my component i commented my code so you guys can understand it easily

```
//start of component
const GraphComp = () => {
  
  //states
  const [valx, setValx] = React.useState();
  const [valy, setValy] = React.useState();
  const  [xarr , setArrX] = React.useState([]);   //[2,4,6,8]
  const  [yarr , setArrY] = React.useState([0]);  //[60,20,40,120,-40]

  // labels are x axis
  // data are y axis
  let x = 10;
  let y = 10;
setInterval(addData(x+=10,y+=10), 15000);

  const addData = (x ,y) =>{
    xarr.push(x);
    setArrX(arrx =>[...xarr]);
    yarr.push(y);
    setArrY(arry => [...yarr]);
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/insert", {x,y});
  }
//func to run map
const showArrayItem = (item) => {
}
  
  // settings graph attribs
  const data = {
    labels: [xarr],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [],
        color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${opacity})`, // optional
        strokeWidth:5 // optional
      }
    ],
  };

// getting screen width to draw graph
const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;


// inserting data into graph
data.datasets[0].data = yarr.map(value => value);  
  

  return (
    <View>
    
     {/* getting x input*/}
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(valx) => setValx(valx)}
        placeholder="enter x here..."
        value={valx}
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />

      {/* getting y input*/}
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(valy) => setValy(valy)}
        placeholder="enter y here..."
        value={valy}
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
      {/* inserting x and y into arrays*/}
      <Button
        title="Draw"
       onPress={() =>addData(valx,valy)}
      />


      {/* display of graph*/}
    <Text>
    {"\n\n"}
      </Text>
      <LineChart
          data={data}
          width={screenWidth}
          height={200}
          chartConfig={{
      backgroundGradientFrom: "#ffffff",
      backgroundGradientTo: "#ffffff",
      decimalPlaces: 0, // optional, defaults to 2dp
      color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${opacity})`,
      style: {
        borderRadius: 16
      },
      propsForDots: {
        r: "5",
      }
    }}
      />

      <Text>
      <ScrollView>
          {
            xarr.map((item, key) => (

              <Text key={key} onPress={showArrayItem.bind(this)}>
                <Text > {item} </Text>
              </Text>

            ))
          }
        </ScrollView>
        {"\n\n"}
           <ScrollView>
          {
            yarr.map((item, key) => (

              <Text key={key} onPress={showArrayItem.bind(this)}>
                <Text > {item} </Text>
              </Text>

            ))
          }
        </ScrollView>
        </Text>
    </View>
    
  );
};

{/* css to style input fields*/}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
});


export default GraphComp
```